# how to ask a function to do something specific in its last call without using the help of the items in a for loop?

Tags: python

I have a complicated code of several classes and functions. one of the functions is called n times and I need to do something specific in the last call of the function. It is too complicated to use the iteratble of the for loop.
I need something that knows that this is the last call of the function, then it does what I want
something like that

> def myfunc(y):
> x = y*2

> if last_call:
> x = y*3

is it possible?

I tried to use the items in the for loop that calls the function but because the code has several classes with several functions, it did not work as there are detailed requirements to call the functions and these requirements contradict what I tried to do.
Thanks

Comment: You should supply an MRE.  The obvious answer is to just modify the loop so that it passes a flag or calls a different function for the last iteration, but you say it's "too complicated" -- why is it not as simple as just adding one extra line of code, either inside or following the loop?  An MRE would help to illustrate the problem you're having and make it easy for someone to offer a solution.

Comment: the for loop, loops over a function that takes a dictionary as a parameter and it gave me an error when I add more parameter to make an if statement such that when I  set this parameter to true do what I want .

Comment: Assume `li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` you can iterate and do something like `[(y * 2) if (idx + 1) != len(li) else (y * 3) for idx, y in enumerate(li)]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The function itself does not know and should not care about the context in which it is called. If you want the behavior to change, you do that by passing an appropriate argument.

In this case, perhaps the other multiplicand should be a second argument; it can *default* to 2, but the caller should be responsible for passing 3 when appropriate.

```
def myfunc(y, z=2):
    x = y * z
    ...
```

Then you can determine the appropriate 2nd argument in the loop

```
for i in range(10):
    myfunc(i, 2 if range < 9 else 3)
```

or refactor the loop like

```
for i in range(9):
    myfunc(i)
myfunc(10, 3)
```

The exact refactoring depends on your use case; these are just suggestions.

In more extreme cases, there should probably be two different functions, with the caller deciding which function to call rather than simply deciding what argument(s) to pass. Here, maybe there is one function to call inside the (suitably shortened) loop, and another to call after the loop completes.

Comment: But good suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use flag. Iterate the calls to that fun and get the last unchanged flag values.

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.